# Smaller version of domain objects to send to a (low memory) client

Tags: c#, .net, oop, conceptual

I have domain objects with lots of properties (members) that I am using in my API. In some of the transactions, it makes more sense to send the domain objects to the client rather than a whole new response class with the same members

Now my question is, is there a way that I **hide some properties of the class** and only send some properties (members) to the client (and in a different call send a different set of properties and hide rest)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new response DTO(Data Transfer objects) classes containing the only properties you want to send back. Then create factory methods for converting your objects of Domain Classes to response DTO.

This will serve your purpose. Later if you want to add new properties in your DTO that actually exist in other domain classes you can add those easily.

Just to add in case you intend to use it. You can have Request DTO's as well, The client's data may not necessarily map to your domain classes. Again you can create a factory method that will convert your request DTO into domain class/classes object(s).

Comment: This is creating a new class...not using the old. Is there a way to use the domain class

Answer (score 0):

As already has been answered, DTO is more suited for this. As an alternative, you can "hide" unwanted properties from the client behind a more specific public interface. Your domain objects can simply implement them.

Example:

```
class Document : IEntity, IVersionable, IDocumentContentDescription 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public interface IDocumentContentDescription
{
    string MimeType { get; }
    long Length { get; }
}
```